# How to change the css class in angular2?

Tags: angular

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="height = height ? 0 : el.scrollHeight">
   Toggle button<span id="Section1_togglearrow" class="pull-right fa fa-caret-up" style="margin: 2px auto; font-size: 20px;"></span>
</button>
```

I have the code as mentioned above.

I want to change the span class to "pull-right fa fa-caret-down" if height is 0.
If height is the element height then I want to set the class to "pull-right fa fa-caret-up". How to achieve this using angular2.

Basically I am trying to toggle and I want to change the icon on toggling.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="height = height ? 0 : el.scrollHeight">
    TOGGLE BUTTON<span id="Section1_togglearrow" class="pull-right fa fa-caret-up" style="margin: 2px auto; font-size: 20px;"></span>
</button>

Comment: Sorry code was missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the calculation of the height works correctly, because my guess is that `el.scrollHeight` is `undefined`. However, I cannot judge this based on your example.

There are two classes which are static in both situations. I've declared those using the regular class attribute in the code example below. `fa-caret-down` and `fa-caret-up` depend on an expression. For those you want to use the form: `[class.name-of-class]="expression"`.

```html
<span class="pull-right fa" 
   [class.fa-caret-down]="height === 0" 
   [class.fa-caret-up]="height > 0">
</span>
```

Refer to the template syntax table within the [Angular Cheat Sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) for more useful template examples.