# ngFor inside ngFor - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

how do i iterate over multidimensional array using `*ngFor` in Angular 2.
Below is the DOM Wrapper im using:

```
<li *ngFor="let menuName of menuNames" routerLinkActive="active" [ngClass]="{'has-submenu':menuName.submenu?.length>0 }">
    <a href="#" [routerLink]="menuName.route" *ngIf="!menuName.enableSM"> <i class="glyphicon {{menuName.icon}}"></i><span class="nav-label">{{menuName.name}}</span> </a>
    <a href="#" *ngIf="menuName.enableSM"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> <span class="nav-label">Pages</span> </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="menuName.enableSM">
        <li *ngFor="let subMenuName of menuNames['submenu'] let idx = index;"> <a [routerLink]="subMenuName.route">404</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And the nested array:

```
menuNames = [{
    name: "Dashboard",
    route: '/home',
    icon: "glyphicon-th-large",
    submenu: [],
    enableSM: false
}, {
    name: "Pages",
    route: '',
    icon: "glyphicon-list-alt",
    submenu: [{
        name: "404",
        route: '/404.html'
    }, {
        name: "Signin",
        route: '/auth/signin'
    }],
    enableSM: true
}];
```

The second loop does not render at all.

Comment: As a side-note. `[ngClass]` can be simplified a bit by using `[class.name-of-class]="expression"` syntax. For more details visit my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168286/how-to-change-the-css-class-in-angular2/42168593#42168593).

Comment: You are right, its neat way of handling such cases :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some minor issues in your code, typos. Second `*ngFor` should look like this:

`*ngFor="let subMenuName of menuName['submenu']; let idx = index;"`

Mind it's `menuName` not `menuNames` and there's a semicolon before `let idx`.

Comment: Correct, although `menuName.submenu` would be better style. Also index is unused and so should be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the error. This is just a straight forward sign that i should stop coding at 4:am :P.